# How i can to combine multiple views to one?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i implements Views with Built-in class-based generic views in django. i using a Listview CreateView UpdateView DeleteView like this.

```
@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class CustomerListView(ListView)

@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class CustomerCreateView (CreateView )

@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class CustomerUpdateView(UpdateView )

@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class CustomerDeleteView(DeleteView )
```

and this urls.py

```
path('customer/', views.CustomerListView.as_view(), name='customer-list'),
path('customer/add', views.CustomerCreateView.as_view(), name='customer-add'),
path('customer/update/<id>', views.CustomerUpdateView.as_view(), name='customer-update'),
path('customer/delete/<id>', views.CustomerDeleteView.as_view(), name='customer-delete'),
```

this code work normally. but i have implement multiple model with this pattern such as Customer,Employees,Woker, ..... and more.

i want to know how to refacetor code like this.

```
in views.py
-------------
class Customer(Somthing): # this include Listview CreateView UpdateView DeleteView
     model = CustomerModel

class Employee(Somthing): # this include Listview CreateView UpdateView DeleteView
     model = EmployeeModel

class Woker(Somthing): # this include Listview CreateView UpdateView DeleteView
     model = WokerModel

in urls.py
-------------
path('customer/', views.Customer.as_view()),
path('employee/', views.Employee.as_view()),
path('worker/', views.Worker.as_view()),
```

how the best way to implements?. thank you for expert.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to combine all four types of views into a single URL since the update and delete view requires an identifier (possibly, the PK). You can group "list & create" views and "update & delete", it will be easy, I think.

Comment: how i can do it combine ListView and CreateView ?

Comment: why don't you use `ModelViewSet`? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: ModelViewSet is in django-rest-framework. but my project not use that.